# Google Drive API and multiple sign in - specify user for export URLs

Tags: google-drive-api, google-oauth

I'm working on an intranet Google Drive app. Users will authorize it with their corporate Google Apps account.

Everything works well, but, users that are using Google multiple sign in cannot download files using the "export URL" (`https://drive.google.com/uc?export=download&id=FILE_ID`), because Google Drive assumes they are using their private/default Google account instead of the corporate account. And the private account is not authorized to access the files.

I guess they can still access the files through the Google Drive interface by manually switching to the correct account, but I need to provide direct access.

Is there anything I can do?

Comment: Are you sure you have the correct explanation for the problem? The exportLink will use the AuthToken to determine who the requesting user is, not a session cookie. It might be worth pasting your request and response into the question.

Comment: We don't have a single param that works all across the Docs types, unfortunately. Try appending ?hd=<yourdomain>, it may work for a large majority of the products.